# find img tag in string and loop through it

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is here...

```
  if (lines[i].indexOf("img") != -1) {                                
  $(lines[i]).find('img').each(function () {
   HeadCTALinks += $(this).attr('src');
   });
```

the string which contain img tag is this,

```
<img height="250" src="http://newsletters.tm..com/epsg/13MR/MCD-CID/11_CC_020783-N9322C/N9322C_Application.jpg" alt="test" style="padding 0 0 0 0;margin:0 0 0 0;" border="0"></a></span></div>
```

Now the problem is its not able to loop through the img tag.....

Answer (score 3):

The image is a root element, and `find()` only works on children.

You could use `filter()` instead

```
if (lines[i].indexOf("img") != -1) {                                
    $(lines[i]).filter('img').each(function () {
        HeadCTALinks += $(this).attr('src');
    });
}
```

or a more general solution, append to an element

```
if (lines[i].indexOf("img") != -1) {                                
    $('<div />', {html :  lines[i]}).find('img').each(function () {
        HeadCTALinks += $(this).attr('src');
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ApLGZ/1/)

also note that your string isn't really valid, as it has closing elements with no opening elements

Comment: @thank adeno i appreciate your help..so i think filter is always good to use for root and if the element is not in the root.

Comment: `filter()` would work on a root element, but not on children, appending to a parent element and using `find()` works on both